# Checking if an element of an array is present in another array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I am writing a php script which aim is to check whether any of the URLs submitted by the user in the text area are present in an array of other URLs. Unfortunately the script does not work as expected and I can't figure out how to correct it. I have the following code:

```
<?php

$gwt_links = $_POST['gwt_links'];
$gwt_links_exploded = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', $gwt_links);

$blacklisted = file('blacklist.txt');

foreach ($gwt_links_exploded as $gwt_link) {
    if (in_array($gwt_link, $blacklisted)) {
    echo 'link found';
}
else {
    echo 'link not found';
    }
}

?>
```

If I submit URLs in a text area, the script returns 'link not found' even if the URLs are present in blacklist.txt file. I suppose the problem lies in reading the file into an array - I think some special characters must be added. I tried removing them by trim, however without success... How should I correct the script to make it work?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: You may have remnants of carriage returns on each of your $gwt_link items following the preg_split.  Does this help?  if (in_array(trim($gwt_link), $blacklisted)) {

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help... I tested it on my hosting with Php 5.3.26 as well as on Wamp Server 2.2, Php 5.3.13.